# Pass variable from window to page

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, window

I would like to pass variable which I insert into textbox in Window to Page in WPF application I only found how could I do it other way.

Basically I need app to prompt for password which I need to use in different page.

I call window from page like this:

```
Password_Prompt PassWindow = new Password_Prompt();
PassWindow.Show();
```

It's just window with a textbox and a button and after I input a password and click ok, I would like to send the password into variable on page from I called the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to achieve this would be to raise an event when you click the button on the window and subscribe to it from the page.

**Window**

```cs
public event EventHandler<string> PasswordInput;

// the function you are going to call when you want to raise the event
private void NotifyPasswordInput(string password)
{
    PasswordInput?.Invoke(this, password);
}

// button click event handler
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the password from the TextBox
    string password = myTextBox.Text;

    // raise the event
    NotifyPasswordInput(password);
}
```

**Page**

```cs
...
Password_Prompt PassWindow = new Password_Prompt();

// add this part to subscribe to the event
PassWindow.PasswordInput += OnPasswordInput;

PassWindow.Show();
...

// and the method to handle the event
private void OnPasswordInput(object sender, string password)
{
    // use the password from here
}
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to `PassWindow.xaml.cs` that returns the value of the `Text` property of the `TextBox` or `PasswordBox`:

```
public string Password
{
    get { return _passwordBox.Password; }
    set { _passwordBox.Password = value; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="_passwordBox" />
```

You could then retrieve the password using this property. You probably also want to block the calling thread until the window has been closed. Then you should call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Dialog()`:

```
Password_Prompt PassWindow = new Password_Prompt();
PassWindow.ShowDialog();
string password = PassWindow.Password;
```

The other option would be to handle the `Closed` event:

```
Password_Prompt PassWindow = new Password_Prompt();

EventHandler handler = null;
handler =  (s, e) => 
{
    string password = PassWindow.Password;
    PassWindow.Closed -= handler;
};
PassWindow.Closed += handler;

PassWindow.Show();
```